# Creating dynamic div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am using jQuery ajax to fetch JSON data.

Below is my code sample. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/milindsaraswala/5v3wensu/) is my jsfiddle.

Now lot of people told me that making dynamic string is not good.

Can somebody give me a better way to create a `div`?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1mkxw',
  method: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    let html;
    $.each(data.results, function (i, item) {
      html += '<div class="tileBlock"><img src="/PublishingImages/' + item.Title + '" alt="' + item.To.Title + '" /><br>';
      html += '<div class="blockCol1 greyLabel">' + item.To.Title + '</div><div class="blockCol2 fareTxt">' + item.Cost + '&nbsp;' + item.From.Currency + '</div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += '<div class=" blockCol3 smallTxt">' + item.Class + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' + item.Trip + '</div><br><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
      html += '<div class="btnHolder"><input name="button" class="btn-finder" type="button" data-item="' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item)) + '" class="searchBtn wth150" href="#" value="Book now" /></div></div>';
    });
    $("#dvPromotion").empty();
    $("#dvPromotion").html(html);
  }
});

// Attach an event listener to the document element (or any other parent element of your buttons)
$(document).on('click', '.btn-finder', function() {
  console.dir(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($(this).data('item'))));
});
```

Comment: `Now lot of people told me that making dynamic string is not good` It depends on the situation. In your case I'd suggest you look in to a templating library as youre storing a lot of UI logic in the JS code as your code stands. There's nothing inherently wrong with building a large string and appending it once though. In most cases that's faster than doing a DOM operation within each iteration of a loop.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan cool that means, nothing is wrong in what I am doing. I mean performance wise also

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div (or any DOM object) object with jQuery and assign properties to it.
For an example:

```
// Create an image tag with appropriate properties
var img = jQuery('<img/>', {
    src: '/PublishingImages/'
});

// Create a div tag with appropriate properties
var div = jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'tileBlock'
});

// Append the image tag in the div
div.append(img);
```

This way is a little bit better (because it improves the readability) than the string concatenation you implemented.

However I suggest you to use a template engine (for example [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)) if you're searching for a long-term solution and better architecture.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to do templating in the native JavaScript, tried in a large scale project. A very small piece is here for POC.

```
function(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
                        var markup = "<a title=\"%ToolTip%\" href=%Href%;>%Text%</a>";
                        var replacements = {
                            "%Text%": rowObject.EmployeeName,
                            "%ToolTip%": Employee.messages && Employee.messages.ClickHereToEdit
                                ? Employee.messages.ClickHereToEdit : "",
                            "%Href%": "javascript:Employee.openAddEditModal(&apos;" + rowObject.EmployeeId + "&apos;)"
                        };
                        markup = markup.replace(/%\w+%/g, function(all) {
                            return replacements[all];
                        });
                        return markup;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually, for this kind of work, create an hidden template in my html, and then use it.

Then for every item i need to place in my html, i clone the template and insert in the place i want it.

I show you how would i do it usually.

**edit**
You can also bind the click on each item when you insert it.

Look at the .click associated to `html.find('.btn-finder')`

```js
var $template = $(".tileBlockTemplate");
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1mkxw',
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    $("#dvPromotion").empty();
    $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
      var html = $template.clone();
      html.removeClass('tileBlockTemplate');
      html.find('.tileImage').attr('src', '/PublishingImages/' + item.Title)
        .attr('alt', item.To.Title);
      html.find('.greyLabel').html(item.To.Title);
      html.find('.fareTxt').html(item.Cost + '&nbsp;' + item.From.Currency);
      html.find('.smallTxt').html(item.Class + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' + item.Trip);
      html.find('.btn-finder').data('item', encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item)))
        .click(function() {
          console.dir(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($(this).data('item'))));
        });
      $("#dvPromotion").append(html);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvPromotion">

</div>

<div style='display:none'>
  <div class="tileBlockTemplate tileBlock">
    <img class="tileImage" src="/PublishingImages/abuDhabi.jpg" alt="Abu Dhabi">
    <br>
    <div class="blockCol1 greyLabel">Abu Dhabi</div>
    <div class="blockCol2 fareTxt">60&nbsp;KWD</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class=" blockCol3 smallTxt">economy&nbsp;|&nbsp;RT</div>
    <br>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="btnHolder">
      <input name="button" class="btn-finder" type="button" data-item="" href="#" value="Book now">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```